# How to get Facebook tagged photos in Groups to appear in profile?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

In a public group, photos can be tagged and the tags are shown within the group. Though, when viewed from a profile these tags do not appear. Is this the proper behaviour that photos within group are not connected to the profile? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Facebook has this set as the default design.

An exhaustive search across the internet has led me in circles. It is not possible to get group tagged photos to appear in a Facebook profile/timeline.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's some issue with your album/picture sharing security settings. Just confirm whether you've set them to share with everyone/friends.

Comment: I don't believe it has to do with security settings. I've had the same problem and I've looked over all the security settings I could find and haven't seen anything to indicate the connections are being blocked or filtered.